# Should I dispose() the Matrix returned by Graphics.Transform? 

Tags: c#, graphics

I need to draw primitives with graphics object with different transformation matrix. I wonder should I dispose the matrix or graphics will do it for me:

```
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(...))
{
    ... some code ...
    var tmp = g.Transform;
    g.TranslateTransform(...);
    ... some code ...
    g.Transform = tmp;
    // should I call tmp.Dispose() here?
    tmp.Dispose();
    ... some code that use g ....
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.transform.aspx

Says:

> Because the matrix returned and by the Transform property
>   is a copy of the geometric transform, you should dispose
>   of the matrix when you no longer need it.

I do not need it after `g.Transform = tmp;`, should I dispose it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.transform.aspx), Graphics.Transform...

> Gets or sets **a copy** of the geometric
>   world transformation for this
>   Graphics.

(emphasis mine.)

When you call `Transform`, you're making a copy of the Matrix, and you should dispose it yourself. As long as you own them, it's always a good idea to dispose objects that implement `IDisposable`, and preferably using the `using(...)` syntax.

Comment: In general, it is only a good idea to dispose of objects that implements `IDisposable` *if it is your responsibility to dispose of them*. While in this case I have no idea and think you're right, in general you need to be aware of the ownership of objects. If you get hold of a stream object from somewhere (think web requests and input/output streams for instance), and it's not your responsibility to dispose of them, and thus you shouldn't.

Comment: As Lasse pointed out, there are cases when you shouldn't dispose objects, for example objects returned from SPContext.Current in WSS/SharePoint. So it is not always good idea.

Comment: @Lasse, @Tomas - thanks both, totally agree. I've updated my answer to make that more explicit.

Comment: My rule of thumb: If you create it, _or ask something to create it on your behalf_, then you are responsible for it (and should dispose of it, etc). Unfortunately, it's not immediately evident whose responsibility it is, but the docs seem to do a good job of clearing it up. :)

Answer (score 3):

Looking through Reflector I see that the `Matrix` struct has a reference to the native matrix

```
public sealed class Matrix : MarshalByRefObject, IDisposable
{
    // Fields
    internal IntPtr nativeMatrix;
...
```

and when `Disposed()` is called

```
private void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (this.nativeMatrix != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipDeleteMatrix(new HandleRef(this, this.nativeMatrix));
        this.nativeMatrix = IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}
```

So the answer would be a definite yes.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes. There is always a reason for using IDisposable. And in this case, the manual also says it. 
Remember that you can use the "using" syntax when dealing with disposables.

Answer (score 0):

If it implements IDisposable, you must dispose of it when you're done (I don't understand why a matrix would need to be disposed, but that doesn't matter).

Comment: This is not correct. MemoryStream, for example, implements IDisposable but does not dispose of anything, so you do not need to dispose of MemoryStream instances. It is this way because it inherits from Stream so it has to.

Comment: @JosephLennox The contract is that you should dispose it. Maybe you can get away without it, but 1) this might break in a future version of the framework, and 2) it is error-prone and tedious to investigate every disposable type you are using to determine whether the Dispose method does something. And it might break if you update the component.

Comment: Btw, disposing a MemoryStream does ```GC.SupressFinalize(this)```, which is something that you want to be done.

Comment: Task also implements IDispose. Microsoft recommends _against_ disposing of it. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/25/10287435.aspx